# How do I check if Touch ID is enrolled but disabled on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I'm using the following logic to check if touchID is available on iPhone and based on the returned value, I direct the user to enroll in touchID or navigate them to setup a PIN. It works fine in the happy path, but if I have even one fingerprint enrolled but have disabled touchID option from iPhone system settings, then it still returns true and navigates user to setup touchID. If I remove all fingerprints, then it works as expected by returning false and navigating to PIN screen.

```
- (BOOL) isTouchIDAvailable {

    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;

    if (![myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {

        NSLog(@"Touch ID checking error: %@", [authError localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I've referred to some questions on stack and apple dev [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication?language=objc#symbols)

Not sure what I'm missing? Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 let context = LAContext()
            var error: NSError?
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                
                if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
                    //this is for success 
                }else{
                   //error.description for type error LAError.biometryLockout, .biometryNotEnrolled and other errors
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

it's not possible. if you have TouchID, you have touchID. But if you want, you can disabled with programaticly. Look at the below code snippet to check touchID is aviable or not.

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Login With your fingerprint with : %@",username];

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Success" sender:nil];
                                    [self loginWithFingerprint];
                                });
                            } else {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   /*
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                        message:error.description
                                                                                       delegate:self
                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                    [alertView show];
                                    */
                                    // Rather than show a UIAlert here, use the error to determine if you should push to a keypad for PIN entry.
                                });
                            }
                        }];
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        /*
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:authError.description
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
         */
        // Rather than show a UIAlert here, use the error to determine if you should push to a keypad for PIN entry.
    });
}
```